# Out of Memory error in opencv

Tags: opencv, out-of-memory

I am trying to make a training data set from the frames of a videos.

For every new frame I am finding the Feature Vector(size is `3300X1`) and **concatenating** with old feature vector to make a training data set. But after reading of 2000 frames I am getting below specified error.

and I am getting error in the below mentione code in second line, i.e

```
   cv::Mat frameFV = getFeatureVectorFromGivenImage(curFrame, width, height);
   cv::hconcat(trainingDataPerEmotion, frameFV, trainingDataPerEmotion);
```

At the time of getting error the size of the `cv::Mat trainingDataPerEmotion` is `3300X2000(nearly)`

and I am releasing old video by using

```
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

before going to process the new video. And the error is

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 3686404 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /home/naresh/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 52
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/mario/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 3686404 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError
```

Can any one suggest me that how can I over come this problem and I have to save the big training data, to train my system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you have not some memory leaks.
As far as I remember OpenCV OutOfMemory error is thrown actualy when some problems with allocation occurs.

If you still can not figure out some memory leak and find the case, you must provide more code. The best will be code that allow to reproduce your error.